# How can i CloseComm, OpenComm, WriteComm and ReadComm with the windows unit?

Tags: windows, delphi, serial-port, communication, delphi-units

I have an old comm unit that uses WinTypes,WinProcs. As i understand these were merged too the Windows unit. 
Are there similar functions in the Windows unit?

Answer (score 2):

Use File API to open COM port. [Here](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-working-asynchronously-with-com-port-on-delphilazarus/)'s sample